# Люди,где нужно ставить id в body { background:url(изображение); }

Tags: html, css

Сегодня столкнулся с проблемой,нужно поставить id в body {  background:url(изображение); }

Comment: Какой вопрос, такой ответ: не нужно ставить id в body.

Comment: Оставь `body` в покое....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я тебя правильно понял, то

```css
#body {
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/000000);
}
```

```html
<body id="body"></body>
```